# Is there a way to make the onclick event function in javascript without including the onclick in html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite a beginner so apology for my question if it's dumb.

I have an unordered list and a button in HTML and I want to make the button show or hide the list via javascript, but I am trying to avoid giving the `onclick` attribute to the button in the `HTML` code.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.onclick = function(){
    
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    if(ul.style.display=='none'){
        ul.style.display='block'}
        else{ul.style.display='none'}  
}
```

```html
<ul id=ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
</ul>
<input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="press me!" >
```

What am I missing here, can't make it work? Could only do it when I included the `onclick` attribute in `HTML` and made a `showhide()` function for its onclick event, but that seems impractical in the long run.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when I run it. Do you see any errors in your browers console?

Comment: javascript.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at javascript.js:3

This is the error i get when checking the browser console.

Comment: Did you load your script in the `<head>` of your page? You're most likely running the JavaScript code before the HTML (ie: DOM) has loaded, so you can't access the elements on the page yet. You need to run your JavaScript code _after_ the page has loaded. This can be done by placing your script before the closing `</body>` tag (see more ways in the duplicate link above)

Comment: <script src="javascript.js"></script>
I have it in the head of my html doc.

Comment: Yeah, you can move that before `</body>` in your HTML, that way your script will run once all the elements have loaded, allowing your script to access them

Comment: Thanks, it clears it up now. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define event handler using `addEventListener` on JavaScript.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    if(ul.style.display=='none'){
        ul.style.display='block'}
        else{ul.style.display='none'}  
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
</ul>
<input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="press me!" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    if(ul.style.display=='none') ul.style.display='block'
    else ul.style.display='none'  
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
</ul>
<input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="press me!" >
```